Different proof that Carathéodory measurable in $\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}^d$) means Carathéodory measurable in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$
A while ago I asked the following question: $\def\RRR{\mathcal{R}} \def\PPP{\mathcal{P}} \def\RR{\mathbb{R}} \def\e{\varepsilon} \def\l{\lambda}$

Let $\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the collection of all "boxes" (or rectangles) in $\mathbb{R}^d$, let $\mathcal P(\mathbb R^d)$ be the power set of $\mathbb R^d$, and let $\l^*$ be the Lebesgue outer measure. If a set $S$ is Carathéodory measurable in $\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, meaning
$$\l^*(R) = \l^*(R\cap S) + \l^*(R\cap S^c) \ \ \ \ \forall R\in\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}^d),$$
is it Carathéodory measurable in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, meaning
$$\l^*(R) = \l^*(R\cap S) + \l^*(R\cap S^c) \ \ \ \ \forall R\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)?$$

The answer by Ramiro is completely OK, but I've been wondering: can the argument be simplified as follows?

Proof: Suppose $S$ is Carathéodory measurable in $\RRR(\RR^d)$ and $A\in\PPP(\RR^d)$. Fix $\e>0$, choose a collection $\{B_i\}$ of boxes covering $A$ and collections $\{B_{ij}\}$ of boxes covering each $B_i$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \l^*(B_i) < \l^*(A) + \e
\ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ 
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \l^*(B_{ij}) < \l^*(B_i) + \frac{\e}{2^i}.
$$
We have that
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\l^*(S\cap A) +\l^*(S^c\cap A) & \le \l^*\left(S\cap\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i\right) + \l^*\left(S^c\cap\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i\right) \\
& \le \l^*\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (S\cap B_i)\right) + \l^*\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (S\cap B_i)\right) \\
& \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty \l^*(S\cap B_i) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \l^*(S^c\cap B_i) \\
& \le \sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \l^*(S\cap B_{ij}) + \sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \l^*(S^c\cap B_{ij}) \\
& = \sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \l^*(B_{i,j}) \\
& \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty \l^*(B_i) + \e \\
& \le \l^*(A) + 2\e.
\end{alignat*}
As the $\e$ was arbitrary, the implication follows.
